# How to return HttpResponseException with Status and text message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, webapi

I have this :

```
    [HttpDelete] 
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteClient(int idCliente)
    {
     

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    }
```

how to return a message text next to status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StringContent("The Message")
};
```

If you want to return JSON (using `Newtonsoft.Json` library), you could do:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StringContent(
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { message = "The Message" }), 
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};
```

Comment: JsonConvert does not exists in the current context

Comment: @joeyanthon -- you have to open Nuget package manager and find `Newtonsoft.Json` and install it

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have `HttpResponseException` in the subject? If you really need to return an error status code with a message while throwing an exception, `HttpResponseException` has a constructor that takes an `HttpResponseMessage` instance.

But in .NET Core that exception only in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim` backwards compatibility package. The recommended way is just to return the `HttpResponseMessage` with an error status code directly.